# Setting up OpenCL in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, gpu, amd-gpu

I trying to get my OpenCL project compile in Ubuntu. I have a Core i5 and AMD HD 5660 which are both compatible.

when I execute the following code

```
cl_int status;
// Retrieve the number of platforms
cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cout << "Error: Getting platforms!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I get `Error: Getting platforms!`

When I execute `clinfo`, I get: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error \n  what():  clGetPlatformIDs'`

I am using AMD driver 14.4 and SDK 2.9 (it is mentioned in AMD installation guide, that setting up these two file will handle registration of icd and environmental variables)

What am I doing wrong that I cannot get my prog working?

Note that I am using Eclipse with correct path to lib (`/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64`). The program compiles correctly.

EDIT

**Installation procedure**

1. first install x64 driver 14.4
2. i installed `AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz` (Untar the SDK  and than executed `sudo ./Install-AMD-APP.sh.`) as recommended in the install guide.
3. validated `AMDAPPSDKROOT 'and`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are correct.
4. created symlink to `/usr/lib64/OpenCL/vendors/amd/libOpenCl.so.1` in `/use/lib` (since it is a x64 bit PC and for some reason opencl looks for x64 driver in /lib)

Comment: What is version of your Ubuntu?

Comment: hi, i use ubuntu 13.10  and 14.04. both have the same issue :(

Comment: And how did you install amd driver and sdk? Are there system (installed via ubuntu's apt-get) amd driver and sdk?

Comment: first install x64 driver 14.4

i installed `AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz` (Untar the SDK  and than executed `sudo ./Install-AMD-APP.sh`.) as recommended in the install guide.
`AMDAPPSDKROOT` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are correct. created symlink to `/usr/lib/OpenCL/vendors/amd/libOpenCl.so.1` in `/use/lib`

Comment: Can you verify that `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd` exists and contains the name of a library (probably `libamdocl64.so`) that is in a directory on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this to work? I'm having the issue myself.

Comment: What's the value of the status?

Answer (score -1):

I think on at least Ubuntu 15.04, you can just install `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates` and dependencies. You can see all the right OpenCL libraries in the core package. I don't think you need the AMD SDK business at all if you have fglrx installed. Andreas gives a lot of [useful information](http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo).

```
dpkg -L fglrx-updates-core | grep -v kcl | grep cl
/usr/bin/atiodcli
/usr/bin/clinfo
/usr/lib/libamdocl12cl64.so
/usr/lib/libamdocl64.so
/usr/lib/libaticalcl.so
/usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so
/usr/lib32/libamdocl32.so
/usr/lib32/libamdocl12cl32.so
/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd
```

You need to have the `flgrx` driver loaded and running.